# How to fix EditText not being rendered?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have modified the tabbed activity example to create my own set of 3 tabs.  Each tab has its own layout file and uses this theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Everything was working perfectly until I added an EditText to one of the fragments layout files.  Then next time i built the app and ran it on an emulator the EditText did not render (however space was left for it).  I then tried to add different types of text fields.  Most of them were to the same effect but the Person Name one had 'name' render next to it as it should but the input box did not show again.  This is the fragment layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.*********.************.MainActivity$FragmentTransmit">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Transmit"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

To conclude, I'm using the Holo theme with no action bar in a fragment and everything works except when the app is built and ran edit texts don't show.  So my question to you is **Why it is not shown?** and **How it can be made to be shown?**

**Edit:** Using a Nexus 5X emulator

[image: What I See]

Android Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The Fragment class:

```
public static class FragmentTransmit extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public FragmentTransmit() {
    }

    public static FragmentTransmit newInstance() {
        FragmentTransmit fragment = new FragmentTransmit();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transmit, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: He doesn't have to this. Using `alignParentStart` and `alignParentEnd`, it simulates the behaviour of `match_parent`. Can you  us more details about an Android version or something? (I tested on a Nexus 5X with 6.0.1 and everything looks ok)

Comment: does not fix the problem.

Comment: does not fix the problem.

Comment: yes I can hint also shows up in the editor and on the emulator.

Comment: I tested your code on different versions and everything still looks ok. Please include some more code that might be relevant to the problem

Comment: Try a LinearLayout. Remove all the alignment code

Comment: In a linear layout it is the same, the hint shows however, I can not select or see the Edit Text.

Comment: Also, you probably should be using an AppCompat theme

Comment: Changing to AppCompat fixes it.